# Find the function in Java for 1=>5; 2=>4; 3=>3; 4=>2; 5=>1; 6=>7; 7=>6;

Tags: java, function

At the moment I am hanging on to a task I have set myself: 
a function should result in the following assignment **1=>5; 2=>4; 3=>3; 4=>2; 5=>1; 6=>7; 7=>6;**

I know that I should somehow use modulo and I already have a solution, `6-i%7`, but of course it results in 6=>0. The other values are correct. I want to avoid an unpleasant if query. Is there a more elegant way? Here is the test scenario:

```
 StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
 String expected = "1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2; 5=1; 6=7; 7=6; ";
 for (int i=1; i<8; i++) {
    int result = ... do something with i ...
    stb.append(i+"="+result+"; ");
 }
 assertEquals(expected, stb.toString());
```

Comment: Replace result in append call with `result == 0 ? 1 : result;` ?

Comment: As I said: I actually wanted to have a mathematical function and no if query...

Comment: `result = (12 - i) % 7 + 1`

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
result = (12 - i) % 7 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
 StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
 String expected = "1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2; 5=1; 6=7; 7=6; ";
 int j = 5;
 for (int i=1; i<8; i++) {
    stb.append(i + "=" + j + "; ");
    j--;
    if(j == 0) {
       j = 7;
    }
 }
 assertEquals(expected, stb.toString());
```